# How to get a fixed axis range in plotly when using restyle

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I want to have an interactive line plot in plotly which would have two buttons and from which you can select the data you want to plot. I managed to achieve this however when the plot is being updated the y axis range changes with each update which is something I do not want. I checked several topics here which suggest to set autorange to False but that does not seem to work. The code I have at the moment is as follows (which does not work):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime



np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(200, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                         periods=200).tolist()

df2 = df.copy()

df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum()

df2['dates'] = datelist 
df2 = df2.set_index(['dates'])
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df2.iloc[0] = 0
df2 = df2.cumsum()


# # plotly
fig = go.Figure()
# set up ONE trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df[df.columns[0]],
                         visible=True,
                         )
             )

buttons1 = []
buttons2 = []

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index,
                         y=df2[df.columns[0]],
                         visible=True)
             )


# button with one option for each dataframe
for col in df.columns:
    buttons1.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[col]],
                               'x':[df.index],
                               'type':'scatter'}, [0]],
                        )
                  )
    
    




# button with one option for each dataframe
for col in df2.columns:
    buttons2.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df2[col]],
                               'x':[df2.index],
                               'type':'scatter'}, [0]],
                        )
                  )
    
    
# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenus = []
updatemenus.append(dict())

updatemenus[0]['buttons'] = buttons1
updatemenus[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenus[0]['showactive'] = True
updatemenus[0]['y'] = 1.12

updatemenus.append(dict())

updatemenus[1]['buttons'] = buttons2
updatemenus[1]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenus[1]['showactive'] = True
updatemenus[1]['y'] = 1

# add dropdown menus to the figure
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.update_yaxes(dict(range=[-400, 400],
                         autorange=False))

fig.show()
fig.write_html("./plot.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaves as you require if you do not `'type':'scatter'` in the **button** definition.  Also I used actual ranges from DF to set y-axis.

```
# button with one option for each dataframe
for col in df.columns:
    buttons1.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df[col]],
                               'x':[df.index],
#                                'type':'scatter'
                              }, [0]],
                        )
                  )
    
    




# button with one option for each dataframe
for col in df2.columns:
    buttons2.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=col,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[df2[col]],
                               'x':[df2.index],
#                                'type':'scatter'
                              }, [0]],
                        )
                  )

fig.update_yaxes(dict(range=[min(df.min().min(), df2.max().max()), max(df.max().max(), df2.max().max())],
                         autorange=False))
```